# Logic apps logs in application insights

Tags: azure-logic-apps

Can I send traces(input/ output) of all actions/steps executed in my logic app to any application insight?
Is there an out of box provision for the same?

Comment: Can logic app do web calls? Which language is it?

Comment: Logic Apps currently support OMS/Log Analytics, Application Insight is on the backlog but not currently supported.

Comment: Any update on this or still on the backlog?

Comment: @DerekLi, is there any updates regarding support of application insight in logic app?

Comment: check out this link for logic app with application insights
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/automate-with-logic-apps

Comment: @GagandeepSingh the link you provided serves a different purpose,  it's intended for monitoring apps that already log into app insights

Answer (score 3):

So far it still seems its not possible to post events or traces to events log directly from Logic App actions.

However, have a look this article here:

https://jlattimer.blogspot.com/2018/03/log-to-application-insights-from.html

It's easy enough to post trace or event to a API endpoint from a Logic App.